# Upload events recurrence end error

Tags: data-loader, event, activities, upload

When I try to upload events via the Data Loader I receive the following error "Select an end date on or before 17/02/2020.: Recurrence End" in the csv file.

The RECURRENCE START DATETIME is 2015-03-17T14:00:00.000Z

Could you please explain and advise how to avoid such error?

Thanks

Comment: What is the start date that you are selecting?
Also,how u are uploading an events? Via Data Loader?

Comment: 2015-03-17T14:00:00.000Z is the RECURRENCE START DATETIME. Indeed, the events are uploaded via the Data Loader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the type of event, Salesforce restricts the number of recurrences that can occur. To avoid the error, you must specify a date/time that is no later than the date in the error message. To fix this, reduce the Recurrence End Date to a time that earlier than stated in the error message.